# How to get URL parameters from a static URL address?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm new to angularjs.

I've created a simple test angularjs app that retrieves some test data with $resource and binds the data to the web page (no ng-view directives). So my test url is `http://localhost/Member`. While this is all good, I'm now trying to get the url parameters in the controller so that I can pass that to the $resource provider.

For example, say I want to query a member of ID 1234 like so - `http://localhost/Member/1234`. How do I retrieve this ID parameter of 1234 in the controller?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use angular routing with [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) and ng-view, you could easily access the `$routeParams`.

In your case, you don't use angular routing, I suppose you're using html5 mode for [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) service. Try: `$location.path()`

```
angular.module('app', []).
config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
.controller("testCtrl",function($scope,$location){
    alert($location.path());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6dD93/1/)

Comment: thanks much on the pointer of $location. it's exactly what i need for now.